# How to join my domain outside my lan network?

Tags: domain, active-directory

I'm having trouble connecting a computer that's outside my building to my domain.
Is that possible?

The goal is to make possible for this outside computer access a AD shared folder on my server that is holding an Lotus Agenda.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To join AD you need to have:

- Access to Domain Controller. Here is list of ports you need: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx .
- Have it configured as your DNS server

The best solution here is to have *VPN*. Ask your IT team to create VPN server and provide you an access. You then connect to your local network through VPN and work as usual. This approach is very common, even Microsoft calls its VPN client "connect to my workplace ": http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/set-workplace-remote-connection-vpn#1TC=windows-7

Comment: The problem is that i'm the IT team...

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this is possible it may not be advisable.

To start with, we would need to understand what version of Windows Server you are using.

The problem with Windows shared folders/drives is that they use technologies based in the pre-Internet past. Typically they use very "chatty" authentication and authorisation mechanisms such as NTLM and Kerberos that don't really work that well over the Internet.

So the best way to achieve what you want is to add a Virtual Private Network (VPN). This creates a private, encrypted channel over the public network of the Internet. There are many ways of setting up VPN's with different products and different costs.

If you are using the latest versions of Windows Server, Microsoft Direct Access would give you the ability to create a VPN using integrated Windows services. It has the added advantage of having the client built in to the latest versions of Windows too.